# Get all Grid Panel Checkbox checked row

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel21233', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.dailywindow',
header: false,
width:  window.innerWidth,
height: window.innerHeight,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    align: 'stretch',
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        width:  200,
                        alias: 'widget.mydailychartgrid',
                        height: window.innerHeight - 100,
                        header: false,
                        store : VehicleStore_Chart,
                        title: 'My Grid Panel',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Plat_No',
                                text: 'Plat No'
                            }
                        ],
                        selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                            checkOnly : true // for prevent clicked grid row and canceled all check box checked status
                        })
                    }//item
                    ,win
                ]
            }
        ]//item
        ,
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                height: 40,
                
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Start',
                        labelWidth: 50,
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        value: new Date()
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'End',
                        labelWidth: 50,
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        value: new Date()
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Generate',
                        iconCls: 'OK',
                        height: 34,
                        width: 80,
                        listeners: {
                                    'click': function(c){
                                        GenerateButtonClick();
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

[image]

How to get which `Plat_No` are checked in my gridpanel row ?

### Updated

```
var record = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mydailychartgrid')[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection()
        for (var j = 0; j < record.length; j++){
        record.get('Plat_No');  
        }
```

anything wrong? error with `TypeError: Ext.ComponentQuery.query(...)[0] is undefined`

Comment: try `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mydailychartgrid')[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection()` refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-getSelection)

Comment: @MMT please provide full detail ?

Comment: @MMT Updated Code, Please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following code.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel21233', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.dailywindow',
header: false,
width:  window.innerWidth,
height: window.innerHeight,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    align: 'stretch',
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        width:  200,
                        //alias: 'widget.mydailychartgrid',
                        name:'mydailychartgrid',
                        height: window.innerHeight - 100,
                        header: false,
                        store : VehicleStore_Chart,
                        title: 'My Grid Panel',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Plat_No',
                                text: 'Plat No'
                            }
                        ],
                        selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                            checkOnly : true // for prevent clicked grid row and canceled all check box checked status
                        })
                    }//item
                    ,win
                ]
            }
        ]//item
        ,
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                height: 40,

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Start',
                        labelWidth: 50,
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        value: new Date()
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'End',
                        labelWidth: 50,
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        value: new Date()
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Generate',
                        iconCls: 'OK',
                        height: 34,
                        width: 80,
                        listeners: {
                                    'click': function(c){
                                        GenerateButtonClick();
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

Instead of 'alise' define the 'name' property and then go through the following code.

```
var record = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dailywindow gridpanel[name=mydailychartgrid]')[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

As it suggests, the query doesn't find anything. You cannot specify an `alias` when creating an instance. You need to provide some other way to find the component (perhaps an `itemId`).

Comment: then use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('itemId at here')[0].getSelectionModel().getSelectio‌​n() ?

Comment: Really, you should get a reference to the window then just ask for:
`theWindow.down('gridpanel')`.

Comment: dont understand, please give me full explaination or example please?

Comment: `theWindow` is the window instance. `down` roots the query and only searches for children of the window. That's as simple as it gets.